# Delphi: Where is Firedac Components Editors source code?

Tags: delphi, firedac

I'm working with Delphi and Firedac components.
I need to find out the Components Editor source code of Firedac components. For example `FDQuery` has a Component Editor with 4 items, as you can see in figure below.

My question is simple, where is Component Editor source code of `FDQuery`? In source directory i'm able to find only Component Editor of `TDataset` (class `TDataSetEditor` in DBReg.pas ). `FDQuery` should have a custom Component Editor, due to its 4 items. Where i can found its implementation??

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: `uADGUIxFormsfQEdit.pas`

Comment: I have not such file in source folder. i'm using Delphi XE5.

Comment: Can't help any further. I have FireDAC 8.0.5.3365.

Comment: In source\data\firedac thre are all design time forms but in source\Property Editors i'm not able to find a Component Editor that links to that forms.